# Two internal webservers, one public IP

Tags: apache, https, webserver, reverse-proxy, centos7

I have two internal webservers both running Centos 7 which need access to ports 443 and 80 for obvious reasons. The problem is only one of them can use those ports because they are on the same internal network and they both share the same public IP address.

What can I do so both servers can access these ports? I have been reading up about reverse proxies or changing the default Apache port but struggling to find an easy to follow guide or solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at [Virtual Hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)?

Comment: You need to better define your use case.  2 webservers serving different domains or the same?  Different: virtual hosts could do it.  Same: you need a load balancer.  Your public IP will be mapped to an internal IP.  So all requests, by default, will end up on the same web server.  Some enterprise network services can distinguish cases like that (split on the domain), but again we do not know enough of your requirements to give a complete answer.

Comment: So to explain further. I have two internal webservers on different IP's. They both are binding to different public facing IP's. Both servers will deal with different websites and therefore different domains. One server is working fine but the second server I cant seem to get it to bind to different ports other than 443 and 80. Because they are both on different public facing IP's do they need to have different ports?